# Adding variable filed and timestamp field - php

Tags: php

I've got problem to adding timestamp with integer , I have *start_date (timestamp)* and *month_pay*. I want to add month of start_date with month.
e.g.

```
start_date = 2015-02-04 12:38:58 , month_pay = 1  
=> total =  2015-03-04
```

```
list($year, $month, $day) = array_values(date_parse($timestamp));
$total_month  = $month_pay + $month ;
echo $total_month
```

In this way , I just show Year & Month & Day , but this is not I want.

Comment: What is your main question? Did not get it.

Comment: You can convert your date string into timestamp (using strtotime).
Then you can simply added the number of months to the timestamp.

$totalDate = strtotime($timestamp) + $month_pay*(86400);

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
$date = date_create('2015-02-04 12:38:58');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('30 days'));
// 1 month is not quite good duration / time interval
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The output would be: `2015-03-06 12:38:58`

Change it to `28 days` (for this year, or `1 month` as suggested by @[fortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720181/fortune)) if you want it to be 4th March.

Comment: yes, you're right, but `31st January` + `1 month` would be end as `3rd March`

Comment: date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $timestamp is a string representing a date,
and $month_pay are number of months you want to add to this date:

```
$month_pay = 1;   
$totalDate = strtotime($timestamp) + ($month_pay*86400);
```

now $totalDate is the timestamp of the final date.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", $totalDate);
```